# jQuery .css({'-moz-animation-delay':'300ms'}) is not working on Firefox

Tags: jquery, css

My HTML:

```
<div class="effect-wrapper">
    <div class="effect-content"></div>
    <div class="effect-content"></div>
    <div class="effect-content"></div>
    <div class="effect-content"></div>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(".effect-wrapper .effect-content").each(function (j) {
    $(this).css({'-webkit-animation-delay':(j * 300) + 'ms'
    ,'-moz-animation-delay':(j * 300) + 'ms'
    , '-o-animation-delay':(j * 300) + 'ms'
    , 'animation-delay':(j * 300) + 'ms'});
});`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F5wzr/1/

but when I see on Firefox using Firebug, class .effect-content only contain style 'animation-delay', not '-moz-animation-delay'.
Can anyone help me with that ? Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It's because firefox use standard 'animation-delay' property, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay

Comment: Don't ever link a new or relatively new user to W3Schools. They might assume the rest of the info is accurate. See this link for more info. http://w3fools.com/